# How to use tabs in Textmate 2 for files opened via Transmit

Tags: textmate, ftp

When editing multiple files from Panic's Transmit, in TextMate 1 they'd open themselves in tabs instead of separate windows.

How can I restore that behavior in TextMate 2?

This was the workflow for achieving this in TextMate 1: http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/06/13/use-tabs-in-textmate-for-remote-files-opened-by-transmit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question a while back, stumbled across your question, but saw there wasn't an answer. Today, I was frustrated, so set about to figure this out.

http://write.byronrode.com/textmate-2-tabs-and-transmit/ has the answer, which is a bit too detailed for an answer here.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: your link is now 404... that's why detailed answers *should* be posted on Stack Exchange!